# Unable to save Linq query data to db in mvc 4

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not able to save data to db i am getting error in following line

```
var data = new ts_grp_perm_mapping
                {
                   grp_id=model.GroupID,
                  perm_id=selectedPermissions

                };
```

This is my model.

```
public partial class ts_grp_perm_mapping
    {
        public ts_grp_perm_mapping()
        {
            this.ts_perm_levelmapping = new HashSet<ts_perm_levelmapping>();
        }

        public int grp_permid { get; set; }
        public int grp_id { get; set; }
        public int perm_id { get; set; }


        public virtual tm_grp_group tm_grp_group { get; set; }
      public virtual tm_perm_level tm_perm_level { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ts_perm_levelmapping> ts_perm_levelmapping { get; set; }
        }
```

this is my action method

```
public ActionResult Index(GroupPermissionVM model)
        {
           var groups = db.tm_grp_group;
            model.GroupList = new SelectList(groups, "grp_id", "grp_name",model.GroupID);
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
             var selectedPermissions = model.Permissions.Where(p => p.perm_status).Select(p => p.perm_id);
               var data = new ts_grp_perm_mapping
                {
                   grp_id=model.GroupID,
                  perm_id=selectedPermissions

                };

                  ViewBag.Message = "Data Stored in Db";
             }

            return View(model);
        }
```

And this is my view model.

```
  public class PermissionVM
    {
        public int perm_id { get; set; }
        public string perm_levelname { get; set; }
        public string perm_description { get; set; }
        public bool perm_status { get; set; }
    }
    public class GroupPermissionVM
    {
        public int GroupID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GroupList { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<PermissionVM> Permissions { get; set; }
    }
```

I am getting error when i tried to save data. I am getting below wrror near  perm_id=selectedPermissions error:cannot implicitly convert type 'System.collections.Generic.IEnumerable to ínt'. Can anybody hint me where i am wrong in overall picture? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign `IEnumerable` value to `int` field. 
I think you should add `First()` here like this `var selectedPermissions = model.Permissions.Where(p => p.perm_status).Select(p => p.perm_id).First()`.

Comment: Samll doubt! How First will work? If i select multiple checkboxes only first checkbox value i am able to save at db.Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want multiple checkboxes use ToList() instead of First(). ToList() will give you list of integers, and then you iterate through that list and save every perm_id.

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to achiveve but the point is that perm_id is integer and it can not be assigned whole list. You have to take list element (which is integer) and assign it to perm_id. For every element of list you need to create new ts_grp_perm_mapping.

Comment: If i do .toList() error apeears near  perm_id=selectedPermissions. Error is cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collection.generic.list<int> to int. So i doubt do i need to change my model? So only one value selectedPermissions is able to take at a time.

Comment: You should write perm_id = selectedPermissions[i] where i goes from 0 to list length. So actually you create many new ts_grp_perm_mapping, not just one. One for every element of the list.